# JQuery - Multiple keys press detection

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, keypress

I am having a problem with multiple key press detection. I am kinda new to js/JQuery, so it could be some silly mistake.. but I cant find it. Any help would be appreciated.

```
    //========== KEY LOGGING ==========
  var pressedKeys = [];      
// == KEYDOWN ==
$(document.body).keydown(function(e){
    pressedKeys[e.which] = true;
        //left    
    if(pressedKeys[37] = true)
        {
        x -= speed;
        }         
        //up    
    if(pressedKeys[38] = true)
        {
        y -= speed;
        }         
        //right    
    if(pressedKeys[39] = true)
        {
        x += speed;
        }          
        //down    
    if(pressedKeys[40] = true)
        {
        y += speed;
        }          
        //+    
    if(pressedKeys[107] = true)
        {
        speed += 1;
        }           
        //-
    if(pressedKeys[109] = true)
        {
        speed -= 1;
        } 
});

// == KEYUP ==    
$(document.body).keyup(function (e) {
     pressedKeys[e.which] = false;   
});
```

EDIT: The problem is, when any key is pressed, it activates all directions.. and I have no idea why.

Comment: e.which doesn't always work.  Some browsers use e.keyCode

Comment: @Samual it does for me, atleast worked when I was using swicth. The problem is, it activates all directions when I press any arrow.

Comment: It could be because you are using = (assignment) instead of == (test)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things I see here:

You are using assignment operator instead of equality operator :)

SO what happens is

```
if (x = true) { /* code always runs */ };
```

Try

```
if (pressedKeys[i] === true) { };
```

=== is arguably better than == since it wont do any automatic casting. I believe that 1 == true will return true but 1 === true will return false

Second thing is are you sure jquery is loaded? Maybe wrap the whole thing around $(document).ready(). See my quick example below:

```
  //========== KEY LOGGING ==========
var pressedKeys = [];      
// == KEYDOWN ==

$(document).ready(function(event) {

    $(document.body).keydown(function(e){
        pressedKeys[e.which] = true;
            //left    
        if(pressedKeys[37] === true)
            {
            x -= speed;
            }         
            //up    
        if(pressedKeys[38] === true)
            {
            y -= speed;
            }         
            //right    
        if(pressedKeys[39] === true)
            {
            x += speed;
            }          
            //down    
        if(pressedKeys[40] === true)
            {
            y += speed;
            }          
            //+    
        if(pressedKeys[107] === true)
            {
            speed += 1;
            }           
            //-
        if(pressedKeys[109] === true)
            {
            speed -= 1;
            } 

        alert(speed);
    });

// == KEYUP ==    
    $(document.body).keyup(function (e) {
         pressedKeys[e.which] = false;   
    });
});
```

Finally, You will still run into errors if x and y really are not defined or if speed is undefined but without more code I cannot say for sure what errors you will encounter.

Ok hope this helps.

You might also want to look at [IIFE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) so you don't leave these x and y and speed variables global

Answer (score 0):

Change your if statements from `if (this = that)` to `if (this == that)`.  The "=" sign actually sets the variable to true, even in if statements.  Only "==" checks to see if it evaluates as true.

Comment: Man, thanks a lot! You just saved me hours of trying to find the problem. Totaly forgot about this :c Shame on me

Comment: I've made that mistake plenty of times before.  Actually, doing `if (this = that)` can be useful sometimes, cause it will test to see if the assigning of 'that' to 'this' actually happened, and evaluate to false if it failed somehow.  Anyway, something to keep in mind.